# Lightbox opens but image doesn't show up

Tags: gallery, lightbox, rollovers

I'm trying to get my lightbox gallery to open up. Everything seems to work up to the point where the image should be showing up. The lightbox background fade is in place, but where the image normally would appear it doesn't. Here's the code of where I'm inserting lightbox.

```
<map name="map4">
<area alt="GalleryPreview1" coords="0,0,180,180" href="GALLERY/Gallery-1.png" rel="lightbox [web]" onmouseover="FWRestore(1,'Indigo');FWSRestore(top.frames,'Indigo');FWLSwap('img4',1,'Resources/gallerypreview1aa.png','','Indigo')" onmouseout="FWRestore(1,'Indigo');FWSRestore(top.frames,'Indigo')">
</map>
```

Could it be because I'm using a rollover image? If I take off the rollover it seems to work, but I want to try and keep the rollover as the rest of my site uses it.

Any help is appreciated. If you need more info, let me know.

Comment: <map name="map4">
 <area alt="GalleryPreview1" coords="0,0,180,180" href="GALLERY/Gallery-1.png" rel="lightbox" onmouseover="FWRestore(1,'Indigo');FWSRestore(top.frames,'Indigo');FWLSwap('img4',1,'Resources/gallerypreview1aa.png','','Indigo')" onmouseout="FWRestore(1,'Indigo');FWSRestore(top.frames,'Indigo')">
 </map>

Comment: That's the code right there. Like I said, if the rel=lightbox tag is removed, the image opens but just by itself in a browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using jQuery 1.9.0? I have the same issue and rolling back to jquery 1.8.2 fixes this.

Alternatively, you can check out the changes made by fernandosavio: https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/issues/29.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove the `rel=lightbox` attribute from the link, does the image load?

Comment: Yeah it loads, but in a new browser window.